# Photoshop starting screen is just gradient circles

Tags: windows, start-screen, photoshop-cs6

I have using adobe photoshop for couple of months. I have photoshop in 2 machines. 1st one is my acer aspire with intel HD Graphics. in this laptop photoshop starting screen looks like this:[image: Photoshop in my laptop.]

2nd one is my desktop without any additional graphics card. I use intel built-in HD graphics to render graphics. Here are my desktop specifications:
Processor: intel core i7 2600
motherboard: gigabyte h61m-s2p-b3 (rev 1.1)
graphics card: No (using built-in intel HD graphics)

Previously photoshop starting screen looks fine on my desktop like laptop,s photoshop starting screen. But after reinstalling windows 7 ultimate (using the exact same OS before reinstalling) photoshop starting screen looks  like this:[image: Problem screen]

Some day ago I have upgraded to windows 10 pro from windows 7 ultimate. I thought it was my os problem. But after upgrade the problem still exist.
What can I Do to solve this problem?

[pics are from web!]

Comment: One of those versions is for Extended... Did you use the correct screen shot? Are you saying that since upgrading your OS, your version of Photoshop has "downgraded"?

Comment: Yes. I have used correct screenshots. I dont think its for my os. I think its for my gpu problem or photoshop setting problem.